# funcion .done no me funciona con ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax, modal

necesito cargar en una ventana modal datos (todos los datos de una tabla), para lo cual en mi controlador tengo una funcion que me retorna un json con la informacion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function listadoCotizaciones(){
        $data = DB::table('cotizacions as cotizacion')
        ->join('clientes as cliente','cliente.id', '=' , 'cotizacion.cliente_id')
        ->join('local_clientes as local', 'local.cliente_id', '=', 'cliente.id')
        ->join('tipo_solicituds as tipo_solicitud', 'tipo_solicitud.id', '=' , 'cotizacion.tipo_solicitud_id')
        ->select('cotizacion.id', 'cotizacion.fecha_emision', 'cotizacion.total_cotizacion','cotizacion.status',
        'cliente.razon_social', 'cliente.rut_comercial', 'local.nombre_local', 'tipo_solicitud.solicitud')
        ->get();
        //dd($data);
        return response()->json(['data' => $data], 200);

    }
```

Tengo la ruta para acceder a los datos:

```
Route::get('facturacion/cotizaciones/listado', [FacturacionController::class, 'listadoCotizaciones'])->name('admin.cotizacion.list');
```

y en mi vista tengo un boton que llama al modal:

el script ajax:

```
   $(".btn-cotizaciones").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('admin.cotizacion.list') }}",
                    dataType:'json',
                    type:"GET",
                        data:{fecha_emision: fecha_emision},
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        $("#modal-seriado .modal-body").html(data);
                    });
    });
```

Pero no logro mostrar nada en el modal (me da error "Uncaught ReferenceError: fecha_emision is not defined" en la consola)

Comment: fecha_emision es el parametro que envias al controller, desde donde lo capturas? no veo que estes definiendo la variable

Comment: Hola, solo es.una prueba, no paso parámetros para cargar el modal ya que necesito el bruto de la tabla, es decir todos los datos que hayan y mostrarlos en una tablita en la ventana modal

Comment: Como sugerencia: todo lo que tenga que usarse para replicar la pregunta, idealmente, debe compartirse como texto. La idea es que no haya errores de trascripción al probar tu código porque el JSON quedó diferente (o se pierdan errores que sólo se verían al usar TU json.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno finalmente consegui una solucion temporal (ya que tengo un error que aun no puedo resolver) pero por si alguien mas lo requiere, asi quedo mi script para mostrar los datos de una respuesta JSON via ajax (en este caso se muestran en una ventana modal):

JS:

```
<script>

    $(".btn-cotizaciones").on("click", function(data) {
        var fecha_emision = $(this).attr("fecha_emision");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('admin.cotizacion.list') }}",
                    dataType:'json',
                    type:"GET",
                        data:{fecha_emision: fecha_emision},
                        success:function(data){
                            var datos = JSON.parse(data);
                            let tabla = document.getElementById("tabla");

                                for(var i=0; i<datos.length; i++){
                                    let fila = "<tr><td>"+datos[i].id+"</td><td>"+datos[i].fecha_emision+"</td><td>"+datos[i].razon_social+"</td><td>"+datos[i].nombre_local+"</td><td>"+datos[i].solicitud+"</tr>"
                                    //tabla.innerHTML += fila;
                                    tabla.innerHTML += fila;
                                }
                            //console.log(data);
                            //$("#modal-seriado #fecha_emision").append(tabla);
                            //$("#modal-seriado").modal("show");
                            }
                            //$("#modal-seriado").append("");
                })
    });
</script>
```

y la tabla en el html:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="tabla">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">ID</th>
                      <th scope="col">Fecha Emisión</th>
                      <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
                      <th scope="col">Local</th>
                      <th scope="col">Solicitud</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

Solamente hay un inconveniente y es que al cerrar el modal y vovler a cargarlo se duplican las filas